# Error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'headerCell') - Creating reactive form inside a angular material table

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-reactive-forms, mat-table

I'm trying to create an angular material table with reactive form.
I need to add some properties, so I'm using formArray.
But my table is not showing  any result, and angular keeps me returning the same error:

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading
> 'headerCell')

This is what I got until now:

**HTML**

```
<button mat-button mat-raised-button (click)="addParameterWhatsApp()" color="primary">Add</button>

    <form [formGroup]="form" autocomplete="off">
    
      <table #table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8" formGroupName="whatsapp">
        <ng-container formArrayName="parameters">
          <ng-container *ngFor="let dados of parameters.controls; let i = index ">
    
            <div [formGroupName]="i">
    
              <ng-container matColumnDef="posicao">
                <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Posicao </th>
                <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
                  <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
                    <mat-label>Posicao</mat-label>
                    <input matInput formControlName="posicao">
                  </mat-form-field>
                </td>
              </ng-container>
    
              <ng-container matColumnDef="valor">
                <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Valor</th>
                <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
                  <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
                    <mat-label>Valor</mat-label>
                    <input matInput formControlName="valor">
                  </mat-form-field>
                </td>
              </ng-container>
          </ng-container>
        </ng-container>
        <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
        <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
      </table>
    </form>
```

**TS**

```
form!: FormGroup;
  dataSource;
  displayedColumns = ['posicao', 'valor'];
  constructor(private _formBuilder: FormBuilder) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.createForm();
  }

  createForm() {
    this.form = this._formBuilder.group({
      whatsapp: this._formBuilder.group({
        name: [],
        parameters: this.buildArrayParametersWhatsApp(),
      }),
    });
  }

  get parameters() {
    return this.form.get('whatsapp')?.get('parameters') as FormArray;
  }

  buildArrayParametersWhatsApp() {
    return this._formBuilder.array([]);
  }

  addParameterWhatsApp() {
    const parametersArray = this._formBuilder?.group({
      posicao: [],
      valor: [],
    });

    if (parametersArray) {
      this.parameters.push(parametersArray);
    }
  }
```

**Image:**

[image]

What I am missing?

Comment: Is this error coming from material itself? Can you share a screenshot of the error? Because none of the variables trying to reach undefined.headerCell?

Comment: I know right? I don't understand either.
I updated the question with the screenshot

Comment: <div [formGroupName]="i"> i is index, could this be the problem ?

Comment: I don't think so, I always use this div when I'm using formarray. But it's my first time doing a formarray inside a table

Comment: I've change some code and I create another question, this time there is no error in the console https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70795052/angular-material-table-not-showing-data-when-using-formarray-of-reactive-form

Answer (score 7):

Possible solutions for others visiting this page.
I got the same error for what seems to be a different reason.

I hadn't created a matColumnDef for all the columns passed to matHeaderRowDef.

i.e. I passed the table two columns "name" and "description" but only used "name" in the html table.

*I could also have fixed the error by removing "description" from the displayedColumns array and leaving the .html file as it was.*

**Component.ts**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-myComponent',
  templateUrl: './myComponent.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./myComponent.component.scss']
})
export class myComponent implements OnInit {

  public displayedColumns = [
    "name",
    "description"
  ];

  public myData = [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "A",
      "description": "This is A"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "B",
      "description": "This is B"
    }
  ];

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {}
}
```

**component.html (threw the error)**
Only one ng-container with a matColumnDef="name".

```
<div class="list-container" fxFlex fxLayout="column" >

    <mat-table [dataSource]="myData">

        <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
        <mat-row *matRowDef="let myRowData; columns: displayedColumns"></mat-row>

        <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
            <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef >Name</mat-header-cell>
            <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.name}}</mat-cell>
        </ng-container>

    </mat-table>

</div>
```

**component.html (worked)**
Now two ng-containers. One for "name" and one for "description".

```
<div class="list-container" fxFlex fxLayout="column" >

    <mat-table [dataSource]="myData">

        <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
        <mat-row *matRowDef="let myRowData; columns: displayedColumns"></mat-row>

        <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
            <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef >Name</mat-header-cell>
            <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.name}}</mat-cell>
        </ng-container>

        <!-- Note the additional ng-container below -->

        <ng-container matColumnDef="description">
            <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef >Description</mat-header-cell>
            <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.description}}</mat-cell>
        </ng-container>

    </mat-table>

</div>
```

Comment: This seems to be the correct answer, either if you specify 3 columns and then HTML shows 2, or you specify that you will have a Footer, and then one of the columns does not have at least an empty footer, it might cause this issue. In my case it was because I was trying to test it with just 1 column, but the array had 3.

Answer (score 1):

At least in the code you show us, **you are not given value to "dataSource" variable**, only have its declaration (it should be 'undefined').

That is probably what is causing it to throw errors.

Comment: I already tried to popule datasource but it didn't work too. 
dataSource = [ { posicao: 1, valor: 2 }  ];

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I had that problem, and I solved it by adding the `MatTableModule` to my module component, which fixed it for me.

Answer (score 1):

Check your spelling! I got this error due to a type-o in my `matColumnDef` directive. Notice the mismatch between the displayed columns and the matColumnDef in this example:

```
public displayedColumns = ['name', 'description'];
```

```html
 <mat-table [dataSource]="myData">
   <ng-container matColumnDef="neme">
     <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef >Name</mat-header-cell>
     <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.name}}</mat-cell>
   </ng-container>
 </mat-table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why angular shows you not related error `ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'headerCell')`.
But the reason your app did not work is because you missed to close `<div [formGroupName]="i">`. you [you can see here after this div is closed](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qvup9i?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Answer (score 0):

In my case i was using *ngIf inside ng-container, i fixed it like this:

```
if (condition) {
      this.displayedColumns = ['no', 'item', 'unit', 'qty', 'al_deli_qty', 
      'deli_qty', 'uni_cost_price', 'tot_price'];
    } else {
      this.displayedColumns = ['no', 'item', 'unit', 'qty', 'deli_qty', 
    'uni_cost_price', 'tot_price'];
    }
```

Like this you need to declare displayed columns, if u are hiding an ng-container